# Can't commit changes to Git via VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, commit

I used the Remote Repositories extension to connect GitHub to VS Code. It cloned the repository, however when I make changes nothing happens in Source Control, nothing like a badge showing a number. When I try to commit, it says there are no staged changes to commit. After doing some research, I saw that I should use `git add`. However, that doesn't work either. It just says that the file name provided doesn't match any files, and if I try to run everything that just doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When using the terminal to execute git commands, check if you're inside the directory of the local repository you modified any files before writing any commands.

After that, you can `git add 'filename' or .`, commit any files and push to the remote repository on Github.

I don't know how you configured your VSC, but your local repository is supposed to be connected to a remote if you wanna do anything with GitHub.

To check that you can try a `git remote` inside your local repository and see the response. If nothing comes, it's not connected.
You can connect using `git remote add <name> <repository url>`.

Once this is done, the local repository will be linked to the GitHub repository.